# Monotouch: How do I retrieve fields in a custom cell?

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios

I have a custom cell (with 3 fields) in a tableview... how do I retrieve the values in each of the fields in the custom cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you want to expose the cell fields as properties (ex: FirstNameField).  Whether you are using MonoTouch.Dialog or UITableView directly, you can cast the UITableViewCell to whatever derived class you have created.  Then you can access the properties of your custom cell.

```
CustomCell myCell = (CustomCell)vanillaCell;
myCell.FirstNameField = "John";
```